# Delete entry with lowest ID

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, symfony

I just want to delete the row with the lowest ID.

I'm trying this:

```
$query = 'DELETE FROM PATH\TO\ENTITY ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1';
$query = $this->entityManager->createQuery($query);
$query->execute();
```

And getting this error:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 53: Error: Expected end of string, got 'BY'

Maybe I'm using the wrong approach.
Any suggestions how to delete the entry with the lowest id in one database call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Kwido said, you miss the entity alias. But the query will still not be able to execute.

First, DQL does not support `LIMIT` expression. It is MySQL-specific feature, is not an ANSI SQL. Other platform drivers have an own implementations of this behavior, all of them provided by common interface: [`setFirstResult()/setMaxResult()`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#first-and-max-result-items-dql-query-only) of `Query` object.

Second, DQL does not support `DELETE` with `ORDER BY` clause (see language [EBNF](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#clauses)). It is non-standard feature too, but can not be implemented for other drivers, so Doctrine does not allow it.

If you need to execute this query, you will have to use a native SQL.

Comment: Okay, that sounds correct. Because if I'm trying to delete the entry via a native SQL it works. I was not sure that DELETE with ORDER BY is not supported by DQL. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = 'DELETE FROM table ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1';
$stmt = $this->entityManager->getConnection()->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
```

You cannot delete or update from entityManager. First you have to select/find the entity from Repository and then remove it. My suggestion works for raw SQL query instead.

Comment: Yes, raw sql is working of course. But I just wanted to avoid raw sql. Thx anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Define an alias for your entity as you use DQL. See: [Doctrine - By DQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-dql)

```php
$query = $this->entityManager->createQuery('SELECT e FROM MyEntity e ORDER BY e.id ASC');
$query->setMaxResults(1); // LIMITS 1
$entities = $query->getResult();

if (count($entities) > 0) {
    $query = $this->entityManager->createQuery('DELETE FROM MyEntity e WHERE e.id = :identifier');
    $query->setParameter("identifier", $entities[0]->getId());
    $query->execute();
}
```

Replace entityAlias with the first letter of your entity classname, which is the most common practice with Doctrine.

// Edit - as @Timurib stated DQL doesn't know the LIMIT. Should've used  [setMaxResults](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#first-and-max-result-items-dql-query-only).

// Edit2 - As ORDER BY is not supported by the DELETE statement, but only the WHERE clause. We're now using another query to return the identifier before deleting. See [DQL - Statements](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#statements)

Comment: Thx, but this query is not able to execute. I'm getting a syntax error probably because of the "ORDER BY"

Comment: @Sploat like Timurib's answer says the DELETE doesn't support the "ORDER BY" clause but only the "WHERE" clause. Will update my answer.

Comment: @Sploat - updated the answer, using a select query to get the first ID instead of using the ORDER BY, which isn't supported within the DQL Delete statements as Timurib stated in his answer.